# How do I update my Sharepoint List based on only the visible rows in my Collection?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

hoping someone can offer some direction on how to solve a problem I am having. I have code that Updates my Sharepoint List Status field to "Approved" or "Not Approved" across my entire Collection. It's working great. However, I would like to be able to filter my Collection and then apply similar code to update the status, but only for those rows that are visible in my Collection. Currently, when I filter the Collection the code applies across the status change across the entire dataset/Sharepoint List. Here is the current code I have:

`UpdateIf( Nominations,true, { Status: {Value: "Approved"}, 'Approved By': varUser } );`

My SharePoint list is "Nominations". Any direction on how I can achieve this?

I tried to update my Collection first and then Patch the Collection to the SharePoint List, but I continually run into challenges with this approach (using Patch), so I was hoping to simply update the UpdateIf code somehow to accomplish the objective. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start with a ForAll() function before your UpdateIf. Then you will be able to loop through every record in your collection table. Once you do that you can apply your conditional logic at each line and make needed updates/patches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same conditions you used for filtering collection instead of `true` in the `UpdateIf` function.

For example: Update all list items with ID greater than 5

Use formula like below:

```
UpdateIf(
   Nominations,
   ID > 5,
   {
       Status: { Value: "Approved" },
       'Approved By': varUser
   }
);
```

Similarly, you can add multiple conditions as per your requirements like:

```
UpdateIf(
   Nominations,
   ID > 5 && ID < 15,
   {
       Status: { Value: "Approved" },
       'Approved By': varUser
   }
);
```